# Using "load data infile" not to a table

Tags: mysql, file-io

Im writing a server in which a certain table is saved on the pc itself and another query select  certain fields from that table(which is saved over a txt file).
The problem is that the "load data infile" HAVE to be written into a table.
I want to do something like that.

> SELECT firstName,LastName FROM (
>            LOAD DATA INFILE '\tmp\table.txt' 
>            FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t');

Answer (score 0):

You can do that very easily.

1. First create the necessary table.
2. The `load data infile` into it.
3. Then run your select from against table
4. Then drop table

Given that you have adequate privileges.

Now in your head just pretend 1 2 and 4 never happened

Shouldn't be hard